# Transforming the variable in Y-axis while plotting

Tags: r, plot, gam

I have used gam to fit a generalized additive model including a spline term. It comes up with the attached plot. I want to have Odds Ratios (OR) in Y-axis rather than what is currently showing the graph. I appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For this you can just return the values of the spline on the link scale (without the intercept) and then exponentiate the values to get things on the odds scale

If you are using `mgcv::gam()` then you can do this as follows:

```
library('mgcv')
set.seed(1)
dat <- gamSim(1, dist = "binary")

m1 <- gam(y ~ s(x2), data = dat, method = "REML", family = binomial())

pdat <- with(dat, data.frame(x2 = seq(min(x2), max(x2), length = 500)))
pred <- predict(m1, newdata = pdat, se.fit = TRUE, type = "iterms")
pred <- data.frame(x2 = pdat$x2, fit = pred$fit[,1], se.fit = pred$se.fit[,1])

## compute CI on the logit (log-odds) scale
pred <- transform(pred,
                  upper = fit + (2 * se.fit),
                  lower = fit - (2 * se.fit))
## transform fitted values + CI to odds scale
pred <- transform(pred,
                  odds = exp(fit),
                  oupper = exp(upper),
                  olower = exp(lower))

## plot
library("ggplot2")
library("cowplot")
theme_set(theme_bw())

## plot on the logit-scale
p1 <- ggplot(pred, aes(x = x2, y = fit)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x= x2, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_line()
## plot on the odds scale
p2 <- ggplot(pred, aes(x = x2, y = odds)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x= x2, ymin = olower, ymax = oupper),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_line()
plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 1)
```

Which produces this:

[image]

The upper panel is just a ggplot representation of the plot you showed. The lower panel is this converted to an odds scale.

You'll need to modify this a little if you have multiple smooths in the model. The line

```
pred <- data.frame(....)
```

will need to select other columns from the `$fit` and `$se.fit` components.

One quick way to do this if you don't fancy doing it all yourself is to capture the output from `plot(model)`

```
m2 <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat,
          method = "REML", family = binomial())
plt_data <- plot(m2, pages = 1, seWithMean = TRUE)
```

Now `plt_data` is a list with a component for each smooth. To recreate the plot produced when you do `plot(m2)`, we need to use:

- `x` — this is the x coordinate data for the smooth.
- `fit` and `se` components contain the y coordinate data (the fitted values) and their standard errors

We'll write a function to add the confidence interval and possible apply the transformation:

```
add_ci <- function(df, trans = function(eta) { eta }) {
  df <- transform(df, yhat = trans(fit),
                  upper = trans(fit + (2 * se)),
                  lower = trans(fit - (2 * se)))
  df
}
```

And apply it to each of the data objects in the `plt_data` list:

```
p1dat <- add_ci(as.data.frame(plt_data[[1]][c('x','se','fit')]))
p2dat <- add_ci(as.data.frame(plt_data[[2]][c('x','se','fit')]))
p3dat <- add_ci(as.data.frame(plt_data[[3]][c('x','se','fit')]))
p4dat <- add_ci(as.data.frame(plt_data[[4]][c('x','se','fit')]))
```

Now we can plot

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = p1dat,
             aes(x = x, y = yhat)) +

  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line() + labs(y = 's(x0)', x = 'x0')
p2 <- p1 %+% p2dat + labs(y = 's(x1)', x = 'x1')
p3 <- p1 %+% p3dat + labs(y = 's(x2)', x = 'x2')
p4 <- p1 %+% p4dat + labs(y = 's(x3)', x = 'x3')

plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2)
```

giving

[image]

Next we can apply the transformation

```
p1dat <- add_ci(as.data.frame(plt_data[[1]][c('x','se','fit')]), trans = exp)
p2dat <- add_ci(as.data.frame(plt_data[[2]][c('x','se','fit')]), trans = exp)
p3dat <- add_ci(as.data.frame(plt_data[[3]][c('x','se','fit')]), trans = exp)
p4dat <- add_ci(as.data.frame(plt_data[[4]][c('x','se','fit')]), trans = exp)

pt1 <- p1 %+% p1dat + labs(y = 's(x0)', x = 'x0') + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))
pt2 <- p1 %+% p2dat + labs(y = 's(x1)', x = 'x1') + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 4000))
pt3 <- p1 %+% p3dat + labs(y = 's(x2)', x = 'x2') + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 250))
pt4 <- p1 %+% p4dat + labs(y = 's(x3)', x = 'x3') + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5))

plot_grid(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, ncol = 2)
```

which produces

[image]

As you can see, you'll need to fiddle with the axis limits a lot as the CI explodes.

Comment: Can this be achieved with `mgcViz` instead?

Comment: How can I make the interpretation looking only on the bottom left graphic? When x2 = .25 there is a 175 increase in the chance of belonging to y category? When x2 = .23 there is a 170 increase in the chance of belonging to y category.?